# PHP: user is successfully logout but after logout refresh home page it shows that undefined variable:

Tags: php, session, undefined-variable

Email is the user session email after successfully logout there is no email exist but on index page is shows undefined index as there is no email after logout.

```
Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS\index.php on line 9
    <?session_start();
?>
<?php
    require("conection/connect.php");   
    $username=$_SESSION['email'];
    $sel= "select * from users where email= '$username'";
    $run_name = mysqli_query($con, $sel);
    $row_user=mysqli_fetch_array($run_name);
    $name=$row_user['name'];
    $userid=$row_user['user_id'];
    $teacherid=$row_user['teacher_id'];
    $userid=$row_user['stu_id'];
    $usertype=$row_user['type'];
?>
```

Comment: How do you perform the logout? Probably by unsetting the session? Then $_SESSION is an empty array, and accessing $_SESSION['email'] throws a warning

Comment: <?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();

echo "<script>window.open('../index.php', '_self')</script>";

?>

Comment: this is my logout page. code.         <?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
echo "<script>window.open('../index.php', '_self')</script>";
?>

Comment: Well, then you should not access $_SESSION['email'] ;)

Comment: i have set it if logged user close the page and enter the home page. there should be a already login status, that's fine. But after logout it shows this notice of undefined index.

Comment: Calling session_destroy() destroys the session, and then $_SESSION['email'] does not exist, and that's why you see an error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [verify that it's set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). That will probably be useful to you anyway, because I assume if it *isn't* set you may want to do something different.

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    // maybe redirect to login?
    // or at least don't show them logged-in user type stuff
}

// your code (in an else block if you didn't redirect in the if)
```